# Print_string or print_char or what? What to use? (NASM)

Tags: string, assembly, char, nasm

I have this program wherein a user inputs a score and my program tell its equivalent letter grade. My program should include B+ and C+, however, it doesn't do that.

Even if I input a score in B+ range, it still outputs B. If I input a score in the C+ range, it outputs C.

I'm just going to put some parts of my code. The 'C' part works but the problem emerges in 'C+'. I believe the problem is in my print_char. I also tried using 'Cplus' then print_string but it still doesn't work. Here it is:

```
outmsg1 db "The letter grade is: ",0 


C:
mov eax, outmsg1
call print_string
mov eax, 'C'
call print_char 
jmp Z

Cplus:
mov eax, outmsg1
call print_string
mov eax, 'C+'
call print_char  
jmp Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_char` takes a single character argument.

```
Cplus:
mov eax, outmsg1
call print_string
mov eax, 'C'
call print_char  
mov eax, '+'
call print_char  
jmp Z
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could make “C+” a string (like `outmsg1`) and use `print_string`.